# How to select max number from varchar type value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table as follows :

```
+-----------+------------+----------+------------+
| letter_no | year_index | auto_no  | date_stamp |
+-----------+------------+----------+------------+
|         1 |        100 | 2018-100 | 2018-12-30 |
|         2 |        101 | 2018-101 | 2018-12-30 |
|         3 |        102 | 2018-102 | 2018-12-31 |
|         4 |          1 | 2019-001 | 2019-01-01 |
|         5 |          2 | 2019-002 | 2019-01-01 |
|         6 |          3 | 2019-003 | 2019-01-02 |
+-----------+------------+----------+------------+
```

The third column contains an auto generated number which consist of the current year, a hyphen & then a index number stating from 001. Auto no field is varchar().

So. I need to select only the number (without year, hyphen or zeros) from the auto number like 100, 101, 102, 1, 2 and 3 so on.

I used the following query to get the desired output

SELECT max(cast(substring('auto_no',2)as signed)) from letter.

But I'm not sure the value (2) placed in the query & did not get the desired output. Can anyone help me ?

Comment: If it's always the same format you can simply modify your existing query to `max(cast(substring('auto_no',6)as signed))`, extracting the string after the hyphen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `substring_index()` and implicit conversion.  For instance:

```
select max(substring_index(auto_no, '-', -1) + 0)
from letter;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this query using `substring_index` and `trim` to drop leading zeros:

```
select trim(leading '0' from
            substring_index(auto_no, '-', -1))
from tbl
```

[Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b613f9/6)